# Use Python API to conditionally update ElasticSearch document

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mappings

I am trying to update a document (by appending elements to a list), or create if it does not exists. For example, I want the document with `id == Donald_Duck` to add the elements of the list `suggestions`, if not present already.

```
name = 'Donald_Duck'
suggestions = ['Donald', 'Donald duck', 'Duck', 'Duck Avanger']
body = {
           "script" : "ctx._source.text += new_suggetions",
           "params" : { "new_suggestions" : suggestions},
            "upsert" : suggestions
        }


es.update(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type='test', id=name, body=body)
```

Unfortunately I get a `RequestError`:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')
```

This is how my mappings looks like:

```
mappings = {
  "mappings": {
    "test": { 
      "properties": { 
        "text":    { 
                    "type": "completion", 
                    "analyzer" : "simple",
                    "search_analyzer" : "simple" 
        }, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?
If I have multiple documents, can I use the same code with the `bulk` API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some typo in your body:

```
body = {
    "script": "ctx._source.text += new_suggestions",
    "params": { "new_suggestions" : suggestions},
    "upsert": {
        "text": suggestions
    }
}
```

Plus, are you sure you have enabled the scripting for updates. Please read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html